# autoTableHtmlToJson coming up null (using jsPDF AutoTable)

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to use jsPDF AutoTable's `toHTML` capability to import an HTML table, but it's coming out null when I do so. As far as I can tell, I'm following the exact syntax and structure that the examples for jsPDF use.

Here's the table HTML. In the function, this passes without problem:

```html
<table id="statementDetailsTable">
        <tbody id="statementDetailTable">
        <tr class="flex-container-row" style="text-align: center;">
            <th class="labelCell">Statement Detail</th>
            <th class="labelCell">Statement Date: <span
                    id="statementDateB">8/28/2016</span></th>
            <th class="labelCell">Account No: <span id="statementIdB">11453</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="flex-container-row">
            <td class="cell">Claim No.</td>
            <td class="cell">Visit Date</td>
            <td class="cell">Activity Dt</td>
            <td class="cell">Description of Service</td>
            <td class="cell">Charges</td>
            <td class="cell">Payments</td>
            <td class="cell">Balance</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here's the function. As I mentioned earlier, all the variables work fine until the line with `autoTableHtmlToJson`. It just comes up as null.

```js
function printStatement() {
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'letter');
    pdf.setFontSize(12);
    pdf.setTextColor('#000000');
    let tableHtml = document.getElementById("statementDetailsTable");
    let res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(tableHtml); //res comes out null
    pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {startY: 0});
    iframe.src = pdf.output('bloburl');
    pdf.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});
}
```

Comment: What is `iframe` here? Do you want to show in iframe or want to download the pdf?

Comment: I want it to show in the iframe so that the option to download or print is there. The iframe works fine as well in execution.

Comment: so, what's not working pdf generation or showing in iframe?